# How to manipulate data from HTML input tag with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a web application using ASP.NET MVC (though I'm still a beginner so I don't know much about C#, I only used VB.net). I want my ASP.NET MVC application to store the content of the HTML input tag like username and password to sign in to my application but it didn't work out.

(PS : I'm still a beginner so please make it as simple as it can get)

I already tried many tutorials before coming here, but none of them seems to work. 
Here's is the code I tried

```
// in the Model: 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MoviesApp.Models
{
     public class Movie
     {
         public string id { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
     }
}

// in the controller
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MoviesApp.Models;

namespace MoviesApp.Controllers
 {
  public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
    // GET: Movies
      public ActionResult Random(string movieid, string moviename)
        {
           var movie = new Movie();
           movie.id = movieid;
           movie.name = moviename;
           return View(movie);

        }
    }
}


 //in views :
 @model MoviesApp.Models.Movie
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Random";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }

<form method="post" action="Random">
    <input type="text" name="movieid"/>
    <input type="text" name="moviename"/>
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think action should look like this. And `[HttpPost]` in the controller

```
<form method="post" action="/Movies/Random">
```

Comment: my first answer is wrong. the true is this:<form method="post" action="/Movies/Random">. /MoviesController/Random is wrong, true is "/Movies/Random".

Comment: I tried both but when i use post it gives me the ressource cannot be found error but when i use get it works but it adds the result to the link can you please help me ?

Comment: I've tried both the way I suggested to you, both by typing "Random" in Action and without [HttpPost] as you do. both worked

Comment: Okey I'll restart everything from the begining and see maybe i made a mistake thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding this to your controller method (you use POST instead of GET in your client side code):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Random(string movieid, string moviename)
{
   var movie = new Movie();
   movie.id = movieid;
   movie.name = moviename;
   return View(movie);
}
```

Comment: I added this HttpPost attribute and i left the method as post and when i run the application it gave me resource not found. but when i changed both the method and http atrribute to get i thin it worked because it gave me this link:https://localhost:44397/Movies/Random?movieid=Shrek&moviename=first

Answer (score 1):

The default `MVC controller route` defined in `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` is

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Hence, call controller method as following

```
https://localhost:44397/Movies/Random?movieid=Shrek&moviename=first
```

[Get vs Post](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: So should i make a custom route or change this default one ?

Comment: Two ways of routing 1) Conventional routing (as given above) 2) Attribute routing. You continue with Conventional routing but make sure you're sending request as per route defined.

Comment: Sorry i missed, you're sending request to MVC controller and not API Controller. I updated my answer. Also in your route, you should not use word 'Controller'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it worked since my link changed to :
https://localhost:44397/Movies/Random?movieid=Shrek&moviename=first

but my method is now get and the attribute is httpget insted of httppost would you please explain what post and get are and when should i use post or get ?

PS: when i added httppost to the controller and set the method to post and the action to /MoviesController/Random it gave me the error ressouce cannot be found